# Conditional search and replace using repeated macro or commands

Tags: search, macro, repeated-commands

I want to search for a keyword, and replace a word in the line that is not a search word. I thought macros may be a good way to do it, but I am open to any methods.

I have something like,

```
blah blah
 check abc = 9 
blah
 check def VS 10 
 check hi and j = 20
```

when I have "check", I want to replace the = a few words down in the same line with VS. There are too many = in the file that are unrelated to it to directly search and replace.
I want to do this on a large file.
I made a macro that contains

```
  /check
   s/=/VS/gc
```

and thought to keep running it by putting a range, or repeat it with pressing a period.
When the second search and replace does not always find =, the range seem to stop working after one attempt. In the same case, the period does not work either, because now it skips searching for the check.

Answer (score 1):

I would combine it with the `:g` command:

```
:g/^\s*check\>/s/=/VS/
```

This selects all lines that has a "check" as the first word and then executes `s/=/VS/` on this line. This will replace the first `=` with `VS`.

You can also use the substitution flags `gc` if you like to replase all equal signs and want to confirm every substitution:

```
:g/^\s*check\>/s/=/VS/gc
```

See `:help :global`.

Answer (score 0):

```
:%s/^\(\s*check[^=]\+\)=\(.*\)/\1VS\2/
```

transforms your sample data to

```
blah blah  
check abc VS 9  
blah  
check def VS 10  
check hi and j VS 20
```

that is any line containing `check` later followed by an `=` sign gets `=` changed to `VS`

Add `c` at the end of the command to have it stop at every occurrence for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have given suggestions for other approaches you could take, but your macro actually works fine. The problem you were having is that you cannot repeat a macro with `.`: this will instead repeat the last action within the macro. To play back the most recently played macro again, use <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>@</kbd>.

There are a couple of small tweaks you could make to improve things:

1. You can't really use `c` in a `:substitute` command within a macro, because you're the macro recording will also include your "answers" to the `c` prompt,
2. As it stands, your macro will stop on every line that contains `check`, and display an error about the `:substitute` not finding the pattern. It's easy to get it to skip lines without an equals sign, though. Just update your search to check for this:

   ```
    /check.*=
   ```

Note also that the macro that you have recorded can't be replayed over a range. Or rather, it *can*, but it won't do what you want it to: every time the macro runs, it will search forwards for the next line that contains `check`, so if your range also includes lines that do *not* include `check`, you will be running the macro too many times, and will likely end up editing text *outside* of the range.